# Onclick Event Issue in IE 7

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, internet-explorer-7, onclick

I'm thoroughly confused now. Exclusively in IE7 my onclick function fails to execute. However, when I run it in IE's console, it works just fine.

I've tried the following combinations:

```
onclick="loadStatsRSH('h',2)" href="javascript:void(0)"
onclick="loadStatsRSH('h',2);return false;" href="javascript:void(0)"
onclick="loadStatsRSH('h',2);return false;" href="#"
onclick="loadStatsRSH('h',2)" href="#"
onclick="javascript:loadStatsRSH('h',2);return false;" href="#"
onclick="javascript:loadStatsRSH('h',2);" href="javascript:void(0)"
```

There are other which I've tried, but now I feel its getting silly. Can anyone give me a hint why IE7 would complain about my onclick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KHY52/ in any version of IE I try it in with this HTML:

```
<a onclick="loadStatsRSH('h',2);return false;" href="#">Click here</a>
```

One possibility is that your loadStatsRSH function isn't in the global scope and thus the browser can't find it (though it would be unlikely that that would be a problem in only IE).

If you want further help, the problem is probably caused by parts of your web page that you haven't disclosed as there is nothing wrong with the choices you have above.  I'd suggest describing/showing more of your HTML and more of your script.

Comment: Actually jfriend00, you were correct in a way. The true source of my problem wasn't my javascript at all, but rather my css. The <a> tag was itself didn't have a set width and height. IE7 needed that, and once added it worked! If you're interested in duplicating the issue, the <a> was also absolutely positioned within a floating div with a set width & height. 

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't be setting a width and height on an `<a>` tag as it's not a block element by itself.  I'd have to see your HTML to know for sure, but perhaps you should set height and width of the contents inside the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Actually there is no content inside. It's a blank <a> tag. It's within a div that has a background, which technically is what the users see. Initially I had it <a> tags set to inherit the height and width of the parent div, but IE wanted a set width and height.

I think you have a valid point though. Perhaps I should consider having those two elements swap places. Layout looks good across all browers, but I suppose I would have to post the code to give you a better idea of what's going on. 

Regardless, thanks.

Comment: You should put some content inside (perhaps a div) and give that content a size.  Then, the `<a>` tag serves to make that content clickable.  It's risky to try to give `<a>` tags a specific size all by themselves.  I think IE has weird behaviors when trying to do that.  Or perhaps your `<a>` tag should be around the div with a background rather than inside it?